# Why is Map[2] updating a wrong key data? Is this a proper way of doing this?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

struct ls{
bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs){
return lhs == rhs;
}    
};

int main(){
map<int,string,ls> m1 {{1,"A"},{2,"B"}};
map<int,string>::iterator i;

for(i=m1.begin();i!=m1.end();++i) {
    cout<<i->first<<" - "<<i->second<<endl;
}     

//If we print data here only 1, "A" data is present.
      m1[2] = "C";
      for(i=m1.begin();i!=m1.end();++i) {     
         cout<<i->first<<" - "<<i->second<<endl;
      }

//the above statement updates m1[1] as "C" even though we are m1[2]
}
```

Comment: [Unable](http://ideone.com/3Zgmc4) to reproduce. By the way defining `operator()` in a custom namespace (and it should be a const method and possibly accept arguments by const reference) and not passing it as a template parameter to the `std::map` is not useful to anything.

Comment: Jack, are you able to see both the entries in map? Also, why should const ref as arguments and method should be const?

Comment: @Jack: Const method?? And why would you take `int`s by const reference?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `operator()` should be `const` because a `ls` instance is not modified by it and const reference should be passed because you don't want to have copies, you don't even need them since you need to make a comparison. This is practically true for all specialization of [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) and similar functions from `<functional>`

Comment: @SandyS: `ls` is not used in your snippet, are you by any chance instantiating `std::map` as `std::map<int, std::string, ls>`? because In that case it doesn't work because the third argument should define a total order on your keys while your implementation is clearly not doing it.

Comment: Now that you edited the question it's clear why it's not working, you are using `ls` as the comparison function but your comparison function returns true if the two elements are equal, which is clearly wrong. You already have [`std::less<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) in STL, just stick with it (by omitting the template argument) unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Jack: No, not for `int`s; that's could even be a pessimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not respecting the contract of `std::map` third template argument which should be the comparison function.

The comparison function, which defaults to `std::less<T>`, must provide a total ordering on the keys of your `std::map`. For this purpose the ISO standard defines that, for associative containers at §23.2.4.3:

> The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation imposed by the comparison and not the `operator==` on keys. That is, two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be equivalent if for the comparison object `comp`, `comp(k1, k2) == false` && `comp(k2, k1) == false`. For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the same container, calling `comp(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value.

Now in your situation you define the comparison as `lhs == rhs` which means that

```
auto b1 = ls{}(1, 2);
auto b2 = ls{}(2, 1};
```

are both `false`, so both keys are considered an unique key (if `a` is not less than `b` and `b` is not less than `a` then `a` must be equal to `b`). This means that on map construction only the first pair is inserted.

But then with `m1[2] = "C"`, since you are getting the reference to the value mapped to `2` and 2 compares equal to 1 according to your function, you update the only key present.

Comment: I was the under the impression that specifying a functor like this results in UB because of §17.6.4.8. So what the code really does is somewhat speculative, although it's likely an implementation would do exactly what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ls` template argument is wrong. `std::map` requires comparison to be implemented via **strict weak ordering**. As §23.2.4/2 of the ISO C++ standard says:

> Each associative container is parameterized on `Key` and an ordering
>   relation `Compare` that induces a strict weak ordering (...) on
>   elements of `Key`.

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare.

Among other things, this means *x* cannot be less than itself, i.e. *x < x* must be false.

Your `ls` functor, however, does exactly that. When `lhs` is 1 and `rhs` is 1, then `true` is returned. The fact that this is incorrect should not come as a surprise; it's really all just a very technical, formal way of explaining what the English expression *"something is less than something else"* actually means in terms of mathematics or computer science.

In any case, since your code does not meet the requirements of `std::map`, your program has **undefined behaviour**.

---

The solution is simple: Just don't use `ls`. Instantiate your map as `std::map<int, std::string>` and it will work, because the default argument is an instantation of `std::less`, which has the correct behaviour.